# AllowDotExit is depracted. What's next?

Tags: configuration

I was using the AllowDotExit option to make two simultaneous requests to www.example.net with two different exit nodes. How can I achieve this now because AllowDotExit was removed.

Comment: Allow DotExit allows people to control what Exits you use, enabling it was incredibly dangerous.

Comment: Any possibilities to make the following requests:

Local --> Exit1 --> www.example.net and
Local --> Exit2 --> www.example.net

?

Comment: Run two copies of Tor?

Comment: Isn't there an option like AttachStream or similar? I heard about it in the past.

Comment: AttachStream in combination with EXTENDCIRCUIT?

Comment: You can do that, it's how ExitMap handles it: https://github.com/NullHypothesis/exitmap/blob/0423c4d557fcefeb6a9d9b8e42d1285a838e8d50/src/eventhandler.py#L56-L120

Answer (score 1):

Configure two tor instances, using `MapAddress` to bind them to specific exit, rather than the dangerous, and thankfully gone, `AllowDotExit`.

For example:

```
# cat torrc-1 && tor -f torrc-1 && cat torrc-2 && tor -f torrc-2
SocksPort 9150
MapAddress check.torproject.org check.torproject.org.0593F5255316748247EBA76353A3A61F62224903.exit
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /tmp/tor
User nobody
Jan 27 22:34:24.453 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.9 (git-64a719dd25a21acb) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma 5.1.0alpha, and Libzstd N/A.
Jan 27 22:34:24.453 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 27 22:34:24.454 [notice] Read configuration file "/tmp/torrc-1".
Jan 27 22:34:24.460 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Jan 27 22:34:24.460 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
SocksPort 9250
MapAddress check.torproject.org check.torproject.org.BC630CBBB518BE7E9F4E09712AB0269E9DC7D626.exit
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /tmp/tor2
User nobody
Jan 27 22:34:24.533 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.9 (git-64a719dd25a21acb) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma 5.1.0alpha, and Libzstd N/A.
Jan 27 22:34:24.533 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 27 22:34:24.534 [notice] Read configuration file "/tmp/torrc-2".
Jan 27 22:34:24.545 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Jan 27 22:34:24.549 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9250
```

Now test that they're working:

```
# curl -x socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150/ https://check.torproject.org 2> /dev/null | grep "Your IP address appears to be"
  <p>Your IP address appears to be:  <strong>93.174.93.71</strong></p>
# curl -x socks5h://127.0.0.1:9250/ https://check.torproject.org 2> /dev/null | grep "Your IP address appears to be"
  <p>Your IP address appears to be:  <strong>197.231.221.211</strong></p>
```

Comment: That's overcomplicated and unneeded for something that is relatively simple.

Comment: I'm assuming they wanted equivalent functionality of AllowDotExit, otherwise yes using circuit isolation would serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Using `IsolateSOCKSAuth` is considerably simpler and easier to do as long as you don't care which two exists are used, just that they are different.

```
$ curl -x socks5h://socks:isolation1@127.0.0.1:9150/ https://wtfismyip.com/text
85.93.218.204
$ curl -x socks5h://socks:isolation2@127.0.0.1:9150/ https://wtfismyip.com/text
2a02:418:4014:1::10
```